# How to model two variables to NOT to belong to the same set partition using Constraint Programming

Tags: modeling, constraint-programming, or-tools

Assume we have two variables $x,y \in S$ where $S=\{1,2, \dots, 1000\}$.
Also, we are given a partition of set $S$ as:

$S_1 = \{1,2, \dots, 249\}$
$,S_2 = \{250, \dots, 499\}$
$,S_3 = \{500, \dots, 749\}$
$,S_4 = \{750, \dots, 1000\}$

How to model a constraint that **prevents** variables $x$ and $y$ both belonging to the same partition.
That said, $x=1$, $y = 2$ is an invalid assignment but $x=1$, $y = 250$ is allowed.

I am using Google OR-Tools Constraint Programming.

(Please note the intersection of any two of the subsets is empty, and their union is the whole set. Each partition is **not** necessarily a full range of integers, unlike the example. For instance, $S_1=\{1,\dots,249,750,\dots,1000\}, \quad S_2=\{250,\dots,749\}$ is too a valid partition.)

Comment: Yes, the partitions wouldn't necessarily be of the same size.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way:
$$x\not=i \lor y\not=j \text{ for } k\in\{1,2,3,4\}, i\in S_k, j\in S_k$$

---

Here's another way, using ELEMENT constraints, as suggested by @prubin.  The following is SAS code, but maybe OR-Tools has something similar.

```
proc optmodel;
   set S {k in 1..4} = 
      if      k = 1 then 1..249
      else if k = 2 then 250..499
      else if k = 3 then 500..749
      else               750..1000;
   num p {1..1000};
   for {k in 1..4, i in S[k]} p[i] = k;

   var X >= 1 <= 1000 integer;
   var Y >= 1 <= 1000 integer;

   var PX >= 1 <= 4 integer;
   var PY >= 1 <= 4 integer;

   /* PX = p[X] */
   con ElementConX:
      element(X, p, PX);
   /* PY = p[Y] */
   con ElementConY:
      element(Y, p, PY);

   con NotEqual:
      PX ne PY;

   solve;
   print X Y PX PY;
quit;
```

The first solution found was

```
(X, Y, PX, PY) = (1, 250, 1, 2)
```

and specifying the FINDALLSOLNS option yields
$$1000^2-249^2-250^2-250^2-251^2=749998$$
solutions, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use OR-Tools, so I cannot be specific about syntax, but I'm pretty sure it has a table lookup constraint. So you can create a table that associates each value from 1 to 1,000 with its partition index (1 to 4), and then just add a constraint that says the partition value of $x$ cannot equal the partition value of $y$.

Answer (score 2):

Using intermediate booleans and `AddLinearExpressionInDomain` you get:

```py
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

model = cp_model.CpModel()
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()

x = model.NewIntVar(1, 1000, "x")
y = model.NewIntVar(1, 1000, "y")

sx = {i: model.NewBoolVar(f"x in S{i}") for i in range(1, 5)}
sy = {i: model.NewBoolVar(f"y in S{i}") for i in range(1, 5)}
for i in range(4):
    si = cp_model.Domain.FromFlatIntervals([250 * i, 250 * (i + 1) - 1])
    model.AddLinearExpressionInDomain(x, si).OnlyEnforceIf(sx[i + 1])
    model.AddLinearExpressionInDomain(y, si).OnlyEnforceIf(sy[i + 1])
    model.AddBoolOr([sx[i + 1].Not(), sy[i + 1].Not()])

model.Add(sum(sx.values()) == 1)
model.Add(sum(sy.values()) == 1)

solver.Solve(model)
print(solver.Value(x))
print(solver.Value(y))
```

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet. One assumption I see you made is each domain $S_i$ is a full range of integers. However, the subsets could be from any partition of the full set.
For instance, $S_1={1, 4, 7}, /quad S_2={2,3,5,12}$, then the sets are cannot be defined by `range(start, end)`.

Comment: You can use Domain.FromValues in that case